# The application closes immediately without errors

Tags: python, pyqt5

Please tell me why the window opens and closes immediately Pyqt5
If I disable the browser_w function, then everything works. and if I turn it on, the window closes and does not display any errors

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout
 
app = QApplication([])

FormRoot, WindowRoot = uic.loadUiType("C:/Users/Danis/PycharmProjects/Folium/ui/startRoot.ui")
form_root = FormRoot()
window_root = WindowRoot()
form_root.setupUi(window_root)
 
FormBrowser, WindowBrowser = uic.loadUiType("C:/Users/Danis/PycharmProjects/Folium/ui/browser.ui")
form_browser = FormBrowser()
window_browser = WindowBrowser()
form_browser.setupUi(window_browser)


class Root():
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.browser = QWebEngineView()
    self.qurl = QUrl('file:///D:/pythonProject/Fire305%20v1.1/map1.html')

    self.browser_w()
    window_root.show()

  def browser_w(self):
    self.browser.setUrl(self.qurl)
    form_browser.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.browser)
    window_browser.show()
    app.exec_()

Root()

app.exec_()
```

I tried to create a separate class for the browser_w function, but the result is the same

Comment: I have submitted an edit that may or may not represent your indenting of your code.  once it appears you might want to further refine the edit to show if the indentation levels and code in there matches what you currently have in your app.

Comment: for the future,  once you have pasted your code.  select it and use the {} button to identify it as inline code in the question you are asking.

Comment: I figured it out, the question can be closed

Comment: @Denis Since others with the same issue can see your question, please add the solution you found by answering your own question.